# Print multilingual characters in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode

im trying to sending a response to a web, with multilingual characters on python 3 but all the time, it comes this:
`"\\xd8\\xa7\\xd9\\x84\\xd9\\x82\\xd8\\xa7\\xd9\\x85\\xd9\\x88\\xd8\\xb3 \\xd8\\xa7\\xd9\\x84\\xd8\\xb9\\xd8\\xb1\\xd8\\xa8\\xd9\\x8a Espa\\xc3\\xb1a".`
When the correct answer is this:

القاموس العربي España.

This is the code:

```
s="القاموس العربي España".encode(encoding='UTF-8')
```

Where can be my mistake?

Comment: I think `.encode(encoding='UTF-8')` is not needed. In python 3, strings are unicode by default.

Comment: Is by default but since it's not working in the normal way i put it in that way.

Comment: u use windows? not sure windows console can handle unicode.

Comment: No, I am using Linux.

Comment: Same here. And  without `.encode(encoding='UTF-8')` I get correct results as shown here: http://i.imgur.com/gnXQTkQ.jpg

Comment: The problem is that i need to encode the text, to send it to a web, and on the Web is returning like this.

Comment: @hidura, how are you setting the `Content-Type` header? `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` should work fine with sending the `utf8`-encoded bytes over to the browser.

Comment: I'm little confused if it is talking about sending a web **response** to somewhere else, or sending a **request**?

Comment: I am sending the response, the request comes perfect. The response is the problem, and yes i have it like that!

Comment: Ah ok. your question was not specific that you are talking about web development.

Comment: @hidura, can you provide some code how you actually send the response (on django, socket or etc.)? It's quite hard to understand what goes wrong (or needs attention) without a reproducible sample.

Comment: I found it! It was a mess with the JSON responser, that i was writing with ensure_ascii=True, and the response was trying to send it as a JSON not as HTML.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: @hidura Why don't you answer your own question and close this question as answered

Answer (score 0):

I found it! It was a mess with the JSON responser, that i was writing with ensure_ascii=True, and the response was trying to send it as a JSON not as HTML. By using the `ensure_ascii=True` the system will print correctly any JSON answer.